# How to move fixed div by scroll amount?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've seen others use `overflow-y:scroll` to make a div move with scroll almost like a scrollbar, however my fixed css configuration doesn't let that work.

[image]

I just have a div.

```html
<div class="scrollBar"></div>
```

```css
.scrollBar {
  width: 2px;
  height: 45px;
  background: white;
  margin-left: 46%;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: fixed;
}
```

I've now tried to animate the div moving up or down with the scroll event using jquery/Tweenlite, however this isn't eloquent/effective.

```js
var multi = event.deltaY >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
var change = (multi * 10).toString + "px";

TweenLite.to($('.scrollBar'), 1, {
  "margin-top": change
});
```

How can I do this either via css or jquery?

css/html for the frame that houses the scroll bar:

```
<div class="frame">
<div id="rightCol">
                    <p>[</p>
                    <div class="scrollBar">
                            </div>
                    <p>]</p>

.frame {
        display: grid;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        grid-template-areas:
            "leftCol topBar rightCol"
            "leftCol center rightCol"
            "leftCol bottomCol rightCol";
        grid-template-rows: 10% 80% 10%;
        grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
        padding: 3.2rem;
         z-index: 10000;
    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what your intended use case is? You want a div to move based on *continuous* scroll events?

Comment: Have you looked into `position: sticky`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: @JoelHager its an aesthetic touch. I need the div to move up or down like a scroll bar, however the rest of my page doesnt move because all the content is already fixed. Thats why sticky position or otherwise doesnt work (see edit)

Comment: So you want a scroll bar that does nothing?

Comment: @JoelHager pretty much - it just moves up/down with the scroll, within a range obviously cant go off the page

Comment: Do you mind me asking why? Having a scrollbar that does nothing isn't the best UI. If you really want it though, I can code something for you.

Comment: @JoelHager its more of a progress bar I guess. showing the progression of a timeline

Comment: What timeline though? If it's linked to a scroll that does nothing it won't seem to be connected. Is it a vertical progress bar you're looking for maybe?

Comment: Do you have the other html/css/js we can look at?

Comment: @JoelHager yes see the edit

Comment: It kind of sounds like you want everything static, and instead of the scroll happening on the window, everything stays the same and the scrollbar is used as a timeline progress bar? But what are you triggering? You have TweenMax() methods, but no TweenMax timeline. You'd also have to use an Intersection Observer or ScrollMagic to do scroll-based triggers.

Comment: @JoelHager im also open to vanilla css/js here. Really anything to get the div to move with scroll. Up and down

Comment: You'd have to use an Intersection Observer (native browser) or ScrollMagic. I understand you want the div to move based on scroll, but you haven't been super clear about what other stuff will do. Is everything just static on the page, and the pseudo scroll bar is matching an *element* besides it? So you have 2 elements, where the Y position of the 'scroll' element is animating the position of the 'div' element that's in the static container?

Comment: @JoelHager thats correct - everything else is static. The scrollbar is in a static div, but we can take it out if necessary

Comment: Right, but are there *two* elements that are moving, or just the one. Meaning, is the scroll bar affecting a *separate* object, or just itself?